# C# Application Multibyte vs. Unicode

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a C# application which imports a 3rd Party DLL using DLL Import.

I keep getting Unable to find entry point error.     This is a screen shot of our log4Net

[Log4Net Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSnZY.png)

I used dependency walker to see the exact signature of the function and it appears to be correct:
[Dependency Walker Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gES0C.png)

This 3rd part DLL is written in C++.   The vendor keeps saying that the application settings in C# needs to look like this.
[Vendor Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhSQx.png)

I don't understand what this means for a C# application.    The vendor keeps telling me that I am building a Multi Byte Application.  I don't understand where is the multi byte settings for a C# application.

PS:  I am sorry I am unable to post code here because of the environment I work in.

Comment: Just a guess, look at project build configuration and build with different CPU architecture to see if it helps. E.g. set to x86

Comment: Please do not post images of code or error messages. This prevents searching and makes the question more cumbersome to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the declaration of the imported function. Probably it should be something like this:

```
[DllImport("ITCtrl2005U.dll", EntryPoint = "SetParmFile", 
  SetLastError = true, 
  CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, 
  ExactSpelling = true, 
  BestFitMapping = true,
  CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
static extern bool SetParmFile(string pathName);
```

Comment: Thanks ...I just has DLLImort.   Trying the other attributes as well.  Will get back to you shortly.

Comment: CallingConvention attribute was missing.